# How can I add bindings to search Hoogle from the Yi editor?

Tags: haskell, editor, yi-editor

I'm trying to learn the **[Yi](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Yi)** text editor. I'm using the default configuration provided with Vim bindings, but I'd like to start experimenting with my own configuration.

I can see that [Gwern's configuration](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yi-editor/yi/master/yi-contrib/src/Yi/Config/Users/Gwern.hs) is based on the Emacs keymap and adds bindings to search Hoogle. I'd like to create something similar with Vim bindings but there's not a great deal of documentation on the configuration API, and most of the [example configs](https://github.com/yi-editor/yi/tree/master/yi-contrib/src/Yi/Config/Users) are difficult for a beginner to understand. For example, what is the difference between the bindings created with `cleverMode` from `Yi.Mode.Haskell` and `mkKeymap` from `Yi.Keymap.Emacs`?

What is the easiest way to start hacking on a Yi configuration? Which API documentation is best for a beginner to start with?

Comment: Check these out too https://github.com/yi-editor/yi/tree/master/yi/example-configs . If you have questions then please file issues on the repository and we can try to answer and document it. We're actually replacing our blank Github page very soon so that's a perfect chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This info is going into the documentation pages, and will be there very soon. The documentation should eventually be available at http://yi-editor.github.io/. Once that is up and running, that should be the best documentation for beginners. Since that could take a while, I'll try and answer it for you here.

This should be a good config to start with.

```
import           Yi
import           Yi.Keymap.Vim
import qualified Yi.Keymap.Vim2        as V2
import qualified Yi.Keymap.Vim2.Common as V2
import qualified Yi.Keymap.Vim2.Utils  as V2

import           Yi.Hoogle (hoogleSearch)

main = yi $ myConfig

myConfig = defaultVimConfig { defaultKm = myKeymap }

myKeymap = v2KeymapSet $ myBindings

myBindings :: (String -> EditorM ()) -> [V2.VimBinding]
myBindings eval =
  [ nmap  "Y"          (eval "yy")
  , nmap' (leader "h") (hoogleSearch)
  , imap  "<End>"      (withBuffer0 moveToEol)
  ]

-- Don't read the following, it's not important.
-- Boilerplate begins here

v2KeymapSet :: ((String -> EditorM ()) -> [V2.VimBinding]) -> KeymapSet
v2KeymapSet myBindings = V2.mkKeymapSet $ V2.defVimConfig `override` \super this ->
    let eval = V2.pureEval this
    in super {
          V2.vimBindings = myBindings eval ++ V2.vimBindings super
        }

nmap  x y = V2.mkStringBindingE V2.Normal V2.Drop (x, y, id)
imap  x y = V2.VimBindingE (\evs state -> case V2.vsMode state of
                            V2.Insert _ ->
                                fmap (const (y >> return V2.Continue))
                                     (evs `V2.matchesString` x)
                            _ -> V2.NoMatch)
nmap'  x y = V2.mkStringBindingY V2.Normal (x, y, id)

leader str = "\\" ++ str

-- Boilerplate ends here
```

Don't worry about the boilerplate. I really think that should be inbuilt into Yi. Ignoring the boilerplate, the config looks very simple.

Understanding nmap, imap, nmap', eval, and leader is important.

nmap and imap are similar to what you use in real vim. nmap maps a key in vim's normal mode, and imap maps a key in vim's insert mode.

eval can evaluate keystrokes. So, the line with nmap "Y" makes Y in normal mode do the same thing that "yy" would have done in normal mode. This is a nice way of rebinding keys.

leader, simply defines the leader key as \. So, now, (leader "h") simply means press \h.

nmap' is required because there are EditorM functions and YiM functions. nmap works on EditorM, and nmap' works on YiM. Understanding this would require some knowledge of how Yi works, which I won't get into. Just to keep things simple, the hoogleSearch function has the type YiM, so you would need nmap' for it.

That should give you the basic layout for extending Yi using the Vim keymap.

Using this config, \h should trigger hoogleSearch, since we bound it using nmap'.

The difference between adding the keymap to mkKeymap and cleverMode, is that, adding it to cleverMode enables the keymap only in haskell files, while adding it to mkKeymap adds it to Yi regardless of which file you're editing. You probably don't care about this too much when you're just starting out with Yi.

I hope that helps. If you have any questions, feel free to mention it as an issue on github, or hop onto #yi on IRC.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'll try to give Yi another go this week.